# html2canvas not rendering image (externally hosted images)

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I have created a game in which users pick 4 images from 4 separate slideshows to create a composite image, which I then want to be able to export to a 'gallery' function on my site. I am attempting to use html2canvas but am encountering some problems

this is my jquery:

```
var shotit = function() {
$('.bodyWrap').html2canvas({
onrendered : function(canvas) {
var img = canvas.toDataURL();
    $('<img>',{src:img}).appendTo($('body'));
        }
    }); }
```

body wrap is a really long html element with lots of child elements in it, but it basically goes like this

```
<div class="bodyWrap">

        <div class="header">
          <h1>TITLE</h1>
        </div>

            <div class="slideshowWrapper">
              <div class="slideshow">
                    <div class="slideshowWrapper">
                <div class="slideshow">
                    <div class="slide">
                       <img class="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/mnJDmlS.jpg" alt="head1">
<div class="emailButton">
 <a class="emailLink" href="mailto:emailaddres@email.com?Subject=Let's mail"target="_blank"><br>Name of Artist</a>
</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                    </div>
                      <div class="prevControl"></div>
                      <div class="nextControl"></div>
              <div class="slideshow">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                    </div>
                      <div class="prevControl"></div>
                      <div class="nextControl"></div>
              <div class="slideshow">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                    </div>
                      <div class="prevControl"></div>
                      <div class="nextControl"></div>
              <div class="slideshow">
                  <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slide">
                        <img https://picture.jpg>
                  </div>
                      <div class="prevControl"></div>
                      <div class="nextControl"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**the images are hosted on externally  imgur and not on my website.**

and then a button which looks like this (for taking the pic)

```
<a href="#" onClick="shotit()">take picture</a>
```

sorry thats probably a bit much code but i just don't know where the problem is!!

anyway, any help or pointers gratefully received! thanks

Comment: Refer this [link](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)

Comment: @Rayon Not found.

Comment: @Murtuza - It's been 5 years since I posted this. Seems like the link is no longer available. I suggest you to refer this https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Try using **dom-to-image** library if your image has Non Latin characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="bodyWrap">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshowWrapper">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://picture.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://picture.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="prevControl"></div>
      <div class="nextControl"></div>
      <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://picture.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://picture.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="prevControl"></div>
        <div class="nextControl"></div>
        <div class="slideshow">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://picture.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://picture.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="prevControl"></div>
          <div class="nextControl"></div>
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="https://picture.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="https://picture.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="prevControl"></div>
            <div class="nextControl"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" onClick="shotit(event)">take picture</a>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script>
      var shotit = function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();
        html2canvas($('.bodyWrap'), {
          onrendered: function(canvas)
          {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          },
          logging:true
        });
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: hey! ah thanks, thats almost done it but its not including the '.slideshow' or '.slide' elements... any ideas why? do i need to add them to the jquery?

Comment: also i forgot to mention, the slideshow uses jquery to function, is that effecting it? (sorry i dont know how to do code here)

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
     timeout: 0,
     slides: "> div.slide",
     speed: 500,
     fx: "scrollHorz"
 });

 $('.nextControl').on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).closest('.slideshow').cycle('next');
 });

 $('.prevControl').on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).closest('.slideshow').cycle('prev');
 }); 

 $('.aboutToggle').on('click', function(e) {
 $(".sidebarright").toggleClass("sidebarrightactive");
    });
 

});

Comment: Pls put relative path in img tags...That will do...Kindly accept the answer if it has fulfilled your query...

Comment: hi, im really sorry but i dont know what a relative path is! i'm really new to coding and trying to learn as i go along, thanks!

Comment: the images are being hosted on imgur, so they dont have relative paths??

Comment: Can you edit your example with the actual image path ?
Try replacing 'https' with 'http' and gibe it a try...

Comment: Added 1 example, they're all the same but with different images/email addresses and artist names

Comment: @Phoebe19, We can not draw images which belong to different host. You must have a server hosting images with the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: @Phoebe19 did you get the solution for images?

Answer (score 28):

You can do so by passing one of the option in html2canvas function.

```
html2canvas(document.body,
{
useCORS: true, //By passing this option in function Cross origin images will be rendered properly in the downloaded version of the PDF
onrendered: function (canvas) {
 //your functions here
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. It really helped me a lot after so much R&D

Comment: One can also use a proxy library https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs