# ngx-capture : Unable to capture whole page

Tags: angular, typescript, stackblitz

hello i am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-capture for capture image, but i am facing some issue,it is capture area which is only visible to the browser,

is there any solution to capture whole page or whole div.

i have check and find this example and also refer this Q : [ngx-capture : Unable to capture <img> inside the screen capture area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73405428/ngx-capture-unable-to-capture-img-inside-the-screen-capture-area)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-capture-div-angular-jvia43?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

this is working but my senario is diffrent

please see following image

[image]

following image when you click on capture whole div will capture because it is visible but when you scroll image and click on capture then image will cut

[image]

is there any solution about that...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Angular and an old version of NGX capture.

This bug has been fixed.