iam working on project but i'm getting this error for html2canvas
  const handleDownloadImage = async () => {
    try {
      const canvas = await html2canvas(cardRef.current);
      console.log(cardRef.current);
      const imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      setImageUrl(imageData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error capturing image:", error);
    }
  };

and Iam getting this error
#4 240ms Starting DOM parsing logger.ts:25:29
#4 273ms Starting renderer for element at 216,32 with size 400x450 logger.ts:25:29
#4 273ms Canvas renderer initialized (400x450) with scale 1 logger.ts:25:29
#4 278ms Error loading image https://userpic.codeforces.org/3332594/title/6e3ce0bb53e6ed79.jpg Home:13441:25
#4 295ms Finished rendering

How can handle this error
i think it's because the image is online it's working for my local images
Help me to fix this issue

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372417/html2canvas-not-rendering-image-externally-hosted-images

It looks like you would need to enable CORS in the h2ml2canvas options for this to work. It would need to be configured like:
const canvas = await html2canvas(cardRef.current, {
  useCORS: true,
});

instead of
const canvas = await html2canvas(cardRef.current);

